# Firmware for Amazon Echo Dot

Tags: amazon, firmware

I received an Echo Dot v3 as the prize of a programming competition, unfortunately it cannot do anything without a permanent Internet connection (*I use tethering and I only have Wi-Fi when my laptop is open, which is not often*).

With a 64bit ARM CPU, 512MB of RAM, 4GB of flash, BlueTooth/FM/GPS, 4 physicals buttons, great microphones and speakers, it has the potential to do useful things.

So I am looking for firmware to put on it, with these requirements:

- I can develop and run my own program directly on the Echo hardware, without an Internet connection (so no AWS/Lambda)
- Have drivers to allow my program to use at least the speakers, and as much of the rest of the hardware as possible.
- Installable on Echo Dot 3rd generation
- Obtainable without paying
- Open source would be ideal, but proprietary is OK too
- Any OS type and programming language is OK